# Sharepoint permissions to send mail with javascript

Tags: javascript, email, permissions, sharepoint-online

I'm using this to send emails

```
function sendEmail(from, to, body, subject) {
//Get the relative url of the site
var siteurl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
var urlTemplate = siteurl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: urlTemplate,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        'properties': {
            '__metadata': {
                'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties'
            },
            'From': from,
            'To': {
                'results': [to]
            },
            'Body': body,
            'Subject': subject
        }
    }),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert('Email Sent Successfully');
    },
    error: function(err) {
        alert('Error in sending Email: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
```

}

This works when I try it with one admin user, but a "standard" user, who has contribute permissions, receives the following error:

```
"error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."}}
```

I'm sending emails directly to a user address, I'm not sending to group addresses.
I've added this to the contribute permissions but still without success:

```
Use Remote Interfaces  -  Use SOAP, Web DAV, the Client Object Model or SharePoint Designer interfaces to access the Web site.
```

I don't know what more can I try,

any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contribute permission level didn't have "send alerts" permission.

After adding that permission ir worked

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending the emails to other SharePoint users?

> This method supports sending email messages only to valid SharePoint
>   user email addresses.

From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.sendemail.aspx

Comment: Solved. It was a permissions issue